# Are there any differences between mounting a /proc filesystem inside a chroot compared to mounting it from the outside?

Tags: filesystems, security, chroot

Compare the following:

```
mount -t proc none ./my_chroot/proc
```

and:

```
chroot ./mychroot mount -t proc none /proc
```

Comment: There's also `mount -B` (bind) option, commonly used to bind `/dev` and `/proc` into chroot jail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no differences with respect to the underlying kernel state.

There is a minor difference with respect to the operation of the `mount` command: it keeps track of its actions in `/etc/mtab`, so running `mount` under `chroot` will update a different `mtab` file.

You could also use `mount --bind /proc ./my_chroot/proc`. As far as I know, there is no practical difference between that and `mount -t proc none ./mychroot/proc`: you can mount the `proc` filesystem as many times as you like, and mount options are ignored. `mount --bind` will prevent you from unmounting the filesystem on `/proc` outside the chroot, but that should never happen anyway.

As an aside, I would recommend `mount -t proc proc …/proc` because seeing `proc` in the device field in a `mtab` or in `/proc/mounts` is clearer than seeing `none`.