# how to mount -t proc proc proc/ with their absolute path for a chroot?

Tags: mount, chroot

as we know chroot needs some fs to be mounted inside chroot directory like the following :

```
chroot_dir=/some/where
cd $chroot_dir/
mount -t proc proc proc/
mount --rbind /sys sys/
mount --rbind /dev dev/
```

**what i want is to mount theses directories with their absolute path**
for sys and dev it's very clear to me !
it can be like that :

```
chroot_dir=/some/where
mount --rbind /sys $chroot_dir/sys/
mount --rbind /dev $chroot_dir/dev/
```

but i don't know how to deal with `proc`
i don't know if it should be like that :
`mount -t $chroot_dir/proc $chroot_dir/proc $chroot_dir/proc/`
or any !

*anyone knows how to deal with this please?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "absolute path" would be as seen inside the chroot.  However, you can mount these filesystems in preparing the chroot, and need not be concerned about making them absolute pathnames.

These questions can be helpful in comparing against your examples

- [Are there any differences between mounting a /proc filesystem inside a chroot compared to mounting it from the outside?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3928/are-there-any-differences-between-mounting-a-proc-filesystem-inside-a-chroot-co)
- [mount dev, proc, sys in a chroot environment?](https://superuser.com/questions/165116/mount-dev-proc-sys-in-a-chroot-environment)

In particular, the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/417004/441480) in the second question citing the Arch Wiki (on [Change root](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root)) is the simplest one, since it uses only the filesystem types (no special devices from the non-chrooted filesystem).  The other answers use the `--bind` option of mount.

Answer (score 1):

From `man mount`:

```
       -t, --types vfstype
              The  argument following the -t is used to indicate the
              filesystem type.  The filesystem types which are  cur‐
              rently  supported  include:  adfs, affs, autofs, cifs,
              [ . . . ]
```

And `proc`, among others.  Therefore, the `-t` argument takes one of a number of filesystem types, rather than a `/a/directory/name`.  Mount as usual will take the name of the system you want to mount followed by the directory to which the system is mounted.  So your command would look like this:

```
mount --rbind /sys $chroot_dir/sys/
mount --rbind /dev $chroot_dir/dev/
mount -t proc /proc $chroot_dir/proc/
```

I second [Thomas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/244595)'s mention you can read more about this subject in places such as [the Arch Wiki article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root) he pointed to (though some logistics could conceivably vary by system, depending on what it is you want to do).

Comment: that means the proc can be mounted either from outside or inside chroot_dir ?

Comment: You can mount from inside or outside chroot_dir, but if you're outside of the directory, you might need to type your path differently.

Comment: yeah ! thanks a lot for your attention :)